# How to wrap a Bootstrap 5 nav bar

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I want my Bootstrap 5 nav to wrap until I get to a xs sized screen and then show the small screen pills. Currently it does not wrap and the menu disappears when xs; however, the pills do not appear. I have:

```
<nav id="myNavbarEP" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-md navbar-sm navbar-xs navbar-light bg-light" style="display:none;">
      <div class="container-fluid"> 
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-2 dual-collapse2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto align-middle">
              <li>
                  <a type="button" class="btn btn-colour1 nav-link dropdown-toggle align-middle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Administration</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a type="button" class="btn btn-colour1" href="BdyWghtMonAdmin.html">Body Weight Monitoring Frequency Administration</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a type="button" class="btn btn-colour1" href="ClinicWorkingDay.html">Clinic Working Days</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a type="button" class="btn btn-colour1" href="ClinicNonWorkingDate.html">Clinic Non Working Date</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a type="button" class="btn btn-colour1" href="SupplementAdmin.html">Post-Training Supplement Aministration</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                 
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-colour1" href="AccountUpdate.html">Account Update</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-colour1" href="CalendarSession.html">Calendar Session</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-colour1" href="CalendarSessionSeries.html">Calendar Session Series</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-colour1" href="ExerciseAdmin.html">Exercise Library</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                   <a type="button" class="btn btn-colour1" href="ExerciseMachineAdmin.html">Exercise Machine Library</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-colour1" href="PatientExerciseAss.html">Exercise Prescription</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-colour1" href="SessionSelect.html">Gym Session</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-colour1" href="PatientIssues.html">Issues/Adverse Events</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-colour1" href="SessionSeriesAdmin.html">Session Series Admin</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
         
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-2 dual-collapse2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-info" href="HelpEP.html">Help</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="LoginRoleSelect.html">Select Role</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="Login.html">Log out</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `flex-wrap` class to the `<ul>`.

Comment: Hi Raxi, almost there. When the screen goes to xs the menu still disappears. I would like the box with three horizontal lines in it to appear (select that box to show each menu item item on it's own line; i.e., stacked).

Comment: I will create a new question for the collapse issue. Thank you for your help.